# Updating gridview row adds new record instead of updating the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update the gridview record outside the gridview, in a form. On edit button click, i have written an event and when it fires, it sends the row data to the form for user to edit it and when i click the submit/update button, the gridview adds it as a new record instead of updating the original record.
Any idea what i am missing on?

**Here is design code with gridview**

```
<%@ Page Title="Add User" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adduser.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmDelete() {
            return confirm("Do you want to delete this record?");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkit1" runat="server">
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="maindiv">
                <tr><!--Hidden field for EmployeeID reference-->
                    <td colspan="2"><asp:HiddenField ID="txtHiddenEmpID" Value="0" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="asterisk">*</span><asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" CssClass="box"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="None" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ErrorMessage="Name is required!"
                            EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmpName"
                            CssClass="error_msg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NameValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name can not contain numeric or special characters."
                            ControlToValidate="txtEmpName" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z ]*$" CssClass="error_msg"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="asterisk">*</span><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="addressBox" runat="server" CssClass="box"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="None" ID="AddressValidator" ErrorMessage="Address is required!"
                            EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="addressBox"
                            CssClass="error_msg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="asterisk">*</span><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="DOB"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dobBox" runat="server" CssClass="dob_cal box" ReadOnly="false" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalenderExtender1" TargetControlID="dobBox" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            runat="server">
                        </ajax:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="None" ID="dobValidator" ErrorMessage="DOB is required!"
                            EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dobBox"
                            CssClass="error_msg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="asterisk">*</span><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Salary"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="salaryBox" runat="server" CssClass="box" MaxLength="8" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="salaryValidate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="salaryBox"
                            ErrorMessage="Salary is required!" Display="None" CssClass="error_msg" SetFocusOnError="true"
                            EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="SalaryValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Salary can contain only numeric values."
                            Display="None" ControlToValidate="salaryBox" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"
                            CssClass="error_msg"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="asterisk">*</span><asp:Label ID="gender" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gendergrp" ID="gendermale" runat="server" Text="Male"
                                Checked="true" /></span><span style="padding-left: 5px;">
                            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gendergrp" ID="genderfemale" runat="server" Text="Female"
                                        Checked="false" /></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="float: right; margin-right: -70px;">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" /></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 70px;">
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelBtn" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                                Text="Cancel" OnClick="CancelBtn_Click" />

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="error_msg"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSum" DisplayMode="BulletList" EnableClientScript="true"
                            HeaderText="Error!" runat="server" CssClass="error_msg" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--div for data display-->
            <div class="data_display">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
                    GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="White" Font-Bold="False"
                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#666666" 
                    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" 
                    PagerSettings-Position="Bottom" 
                    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                    >
                    <Columns>
<%--                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="EmpID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

--%>                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID"  
                            SortExpression="EmployeeID" Visible="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="EmployeeName"
                            ItemStyle-Width="130px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="130px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfBirth" HeaderText="DoB" SortExpression="DateOfBirth"
                            DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" 
                            SortExpression="Salary">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="90px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" ItemStyle-Width="90px"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="70px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="EditBtn" runat="server" Text="Select" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="EditBtn_Click" />
                                <asp:Button  ID="DelBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="DelBtn_Click" OnClientClick="confirmDelete()" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="Gray" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small; color: Green; font-weight: bold;">
                    You are viewing page <%=GridView1.PageIndex + 1%> of <%=GridView1.PageCount%>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlCommand cmd;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }
    protected void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ClearForm();
        }
    }


    protected void CalenderExtender1_DatePick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dobBox.Text = CalenderExtender1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        CalenderExtender1.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void DatePick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalenderExtender1.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                string EmpName = txtEmpName.Text;
                string address = addressBox.Text;
                DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(dobBox.Text);
                decimal salary = Convert.ToDecimal(salaryBox.Text);
                bool gender = (gendermale.Checked == true ? true : false);

                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpConstr"].ConnectionString;

                con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = constr;

                con.Open();
                int count=0;
                if (txtHiddenEmpID.Value != "") //insert
                {
                    string query = "Insert into Employee (EmployeeName,Address,DateOfBirth,Salary,Gender) Values(@enm,@address,@dob,@salary,@gender)";

                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enm", EmpName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", salary);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);


                    count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    // update

                }


                if (count == 1)
                {
                    ClearForm();
                }

                con.Close();
                GetData();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    #region Public Functions
    public void ClearForm()
    {

        txtEmpName.Text = string.Empty;
        addressBox.Text = string.Empty;
        dobBox.Text = string.Empty;
        salaryBox.Text = string.Empty;
        lblError.Text = string.Empty;
        if (genderfemale.Checked)
        {
            genderfemale.Checked = false;
            gendermale.Checked = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            gendermale.Checked = true;
        }
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpConstr"].ConnectionString;

        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = constr;

        con.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * from Employee Order by EmployeeID DESC";
        SqlDataAdapter sqladpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        sqladpt.Fill(dt);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();


    }
    #endregion

    #region GridView Functions
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "True")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Female";

            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //select data to display when gridview select button is clicked
    //source: www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-delete-records-in-gridview-with.html


    protected void EditBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        //Get the row that contains this button
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int index = gvr.RowIndex;
        string ID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpConstr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        string strSQL = "SELECT * from Employee where employeeid = " + Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL,constr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sqlAdpt.Fill(dt);

        txtHiddenEmpID.Value = ID;
        txtEmpName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].ToString();
        addressBox.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        dobBox.Text =  Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        salaryBox.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString();
        string gender = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
        if (gender == "Male")
        {
            gendermale.Checked = true;
            genderfemale.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gendermale.Checked = false;
            genderfemale.Checked = true; 
        }
        GetData();
    }

    //Delete record from Gridview
    public string date { get; set; }
    protected void DelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        //getting particular row linkbutton
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        //getting userid of particular row
        int EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string username = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Employee where EmployeeID=" + EmpID, con);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            GetData();
            //Displaying alert message after successfully deletion of user
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + username + " details deleted successfully')", true);
        }
        GetData();
    }

    public string Constr { get; set; }


    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Button1_Click`? You have `insert` query. I don't see any `update` query in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Bharadwaj ji for notifying me about that. So i just add UPDATE query in the "EditBtn_Click" block and it should work? EditBtn_Click is the event for update operation.

Comment: Yes it will work, only if you are updating with correct conditions. I recommend you to build `update` query in query builder (like sql server editor) and then use it in code, for better results.

Comment: Thank you @Bharadwaj ji. Really very helpful. Yes i will use query builder for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Put the following Code to update table using sql query to

```
string query = "update Employee set EmployeeName=@enm,Address=@address, DateOfBirth= 
 @dob, Salary=@salary,Gender=@gender where EmployeeID=@EmpID" 

                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", EmpID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enm", EmpName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", salary);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);


                count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How this may help you.

Comment: i definitely voted up but unfortunately i do not have necessary reputation count to vote up. I am so sorry for this. I am trying to up my reputation score and will vote up this ans. as soon as qualify to vote up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one simple query for that,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT column_name FROM this_table WHERE  some_col = '1' ) 
UPDATE this_table SET column_name='2'  WHERE  column_name = '1' 
ELSE 
INSERT into this_table (column_name) values (4)
```

Comment: Arjun ji, do i need only to work on sql side with this query or i will need to play with my code behind as well to have an UPDATE event. I am sorry for mixing up the mind, if so.

Comment: Yes Moin Shaikh, just you need to work on SQL part where you need to take care before adding or removing records from original data. Hope it was helpful to you...

Comment: Welcome @Moin Shaikh,,, :)